# Find unused functions in a C project by static analysis

Tags: c, gcc, static-analysis, dead-code

I am trying to run static analysis on a C project to identify dead code i.e functions or code lines that are never ever called. I can build this project with Visual Studio .Net for Windows or using gcc for Linux. I have been trying to find some reasonable tool that can do this for me but so far I have not succeeded. I have read related questions on Stack Overflow i.e [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321241/dead-code-identification-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229069/dead-code-detection-in-legacy-c-c-project) and I have tried to use `-Wunreachable-code` with gcc but the output in gcc is not very helpful. It is of the following format

```
/home/adnan/my_socket.c: In function ‘my_sockNtoH32’: 
/home/adnan/my_socket.c:666: warning: will never be executed
```

but when I look at line 666 in `my_socket.c`, it's actually inside another function that is being called from function my_sockNtoH32() and will not be executed for this specific instance but will be executed when called from some other functions.

What I need is to find the code which will never be executed. Can someone plz help with this?

PS: I can't convince management to buy a tool for this task, so please stick to free/open source tools.

Comment: what has this to do with .net?

Comment: @phresnel: As I said I can use either VS .Net or gcc to build the project so a static analysis tool for VS .Net can also work for me

Comment: When gcc says "will never be executed", it generally means just that, never. Not "will rarely be executed" or somesuch. Please post an example of code which you think is misanalysed by gcc.

Comment: `VS .net` is the name of an IDE. If you scroll over the .net-tag you'll see it is not about the IDE named `VS .net` but about the framework named `.net`, therefore, that tag is not proper for your question.

Comment: Your explanation starting with "but when I look at line 666 in …" makes it look like you are looking for a modular dead code analysis or such other impossible beast. As n.m. suggests, you should provide a small example.

Comment: Just for your information, Wunreachable-code has been removed from gcc in [January 2010](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs?view=revision&revision=155645) (probably version 4.4.3) because it [was considered broken](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2011-05/msg00362.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When GCC says "will never be executed", it means it. You may have a bug that, in fact, does make that dead code. For example, something like:

```
if (a = 42) {
    // some code
} else {
    // warning: unreachable code
}
```

Without seeing the code it's not possible to be specific, of course.

Note that if there is a macro at line 666, it's possible GCC refers to a part of that macro as well.

Comment: Yes, on high optimization levels, unreachable edges in the CFG will be pruned, eliminating dead code.

Comment: The *complement* of this answer isn't quite what you expect.  If GCC doesn't say "it will never be executed", you don't know that it isn't actually dead.  Just that GCC can't tell by looking at this compilation unit.  See my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 3):

If GCC isn't cutting it for you, try [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) (or more accurately, its [static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/)). It (generally, your mileage may vary of course) has a much better static analysis than GCC (and produces much better output). It's used in Apple's Xcode but it's open-source and can be used seperately.

Answer (score 1):

GCC will help you find dead code *within* a compilation.  I'd be surprised if it can find dead code *across* multiple compilation units.  A file-level declaration of a function or variable in a compilation unit means that some other compilation unit might reference it.  So anything declared at the top level of a file, GCC can't eliminate, as it arguably only sees one compilation unit at a time.

The problem gets get harder.  Imagine that compilation unit A declares function a, and compilation unit B has a function b that calls a.   Is a dead?   On the face of it, no.   But in fact, it depends; if b is dead, and the only reference to a is in b, then a is dead, too.  We get the same problem if b merely takes **&a** and puts it into an array X.   Now to decide if a is dead, we need a points-to analysis across the entire system, to see if that pointer to a is used *anywhere*.

To get this kind of accurate "dead" information, you need a global view of the entire set of compilation units, and need to compute a points-to analysis, followed by the construction of a call-graph based on that points-to analysis.   Function a is dead only if the call graph (as a tree,
with main as the root) doesn't reference it somewhere. 
(Some caveats are necessary: whatever the analysis is, as a practical matter it must be conservative, so even a full-points to analysis may not identify a function correctly as dead.  You also have to worry about uses of a C artifact from outside the set of C functions, e.g., a call to a from some bit of assembler code).

Threading makes this worse; each thread has some root function which is probably at the top of the call DAG.   Since how a thread gets started isn't defined by C compilers, it should be clear that to determine if a multithreaded C application has dead code, somehow the analysis has to be told the thread root functions, or be told how to discover them by looking for thread-initialization primitives.

You aren't getting a lot responses on how to get a correct answer. While it isn't open source, our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its [C Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html) has all the machinery to do this, including C parsers, [control- and dataflow- analysis, local and global points-to analysis, and global call graph construction.](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/FlowAnalysis.html)  DMS is easily customized to include extra information such as external calls from assembler, and/or a list of thread roots or specific source-patterns that are thread initialization calls, and we've actually done that (easily) for some large embedded engine controllers with millions of lines of code.  DMS has been applied to systems as large as 26 million lines of code (some 18,000 compilation units) for the purpose of building such calls graphs.

[An interesting aside: in processing individual comilation units, DMS for scaling reasons in effect deletes symbols and related code that aren't used in that compilation unit.  Remarkably, this gets rid of about 95% of code by volume when you take into account the iceberg usually hiding in the include file nest.  It says C software typically has poorly factored include files.  I suspect you all know that already.]

Tools like GCC will remove dead code *while compiling*.  That's helpful, but the dead code is still lying around in your compilation unit *source code* using up developer's attention (they have to figure out if it is dead, too!).   DMS in its program transformation mode can be configured, modulo some preprocessor issues, to actually remove that dead code *from the source*.  On very large software systems, you don't really want to do this by hand.