# Detection of unused function and code in C

Tags: c

Iam writing a program in C. Is there any way(gcc options) to identify the unused code and functions during compilation time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static analysis on a C project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387205/static-analysis-on-a-c-project)

Answer (score 4):

If you use `-Wunused-function`, you will get warnings about unused functions.  (Note that this is also enabled when you use `-Wall`).

See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html for more details.

Comment: I was wondering if unsed-functions will be actually optimized out by a compiler. It'd be logical to remove them out at the compile time (except in libs).

Comment: The will be removed, but this only applies to functions with internal (static) linkage. External functions are never optimized out by the compiler, but depending on options, it may be possible for the linker to optimize them out.

Answer (score 3):

`gcc -Wall` will warn you about unused `static` functions and some other types of unreachable code. It will not warn about unused functions with external linkage, though, since that would make it impossible to write a library.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do this at compile time. All the compiler does is create object code - it does not know about external code that may or may not call functions you write. Have you ever written a program that calls `main`? It is the linker that determines if a function (specifically, a symbol) is used in the application. And I think GCC will remove unused symbols by default.

Comment: `extern` functions cannot be identified, but `static` functions can be (and indeed are).

Comment: @Oli: Functions are external linkage by default so the compiler can't identify them as unused. The linker can, since nothing references the symbol. Unless you're using a linker that can export symbols (i.e. creating a shared object / dll / etc), in which the function isn't removed if it's listed as an exported function.