# Using GCC to find unreachable functions ("dead code")

Tags: c++, gcc, dead-code

I was looking for a way of finding statically unreachable functions in a (very) big C++ project. I had tried using doxygen and other static analysis tools suggested here but it seemed that the project is too complicated for them to handle. Finally i decided that using GCC tools (g++, gprof, gcov, etc.) is the safest option, although I couldn't figure out how to do it.

I think the g++ optimizations eliminate statically unreachable functions but I'm not sure how to get the names of the functions it eliminates.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229069/dead-code-detection-in-legacy-c-c-project

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dead code optimization is typically done by the linker - the compiler doesn't have the overview. However, the compiler might have eliminated unused `static` functions (as they have internal linkage).

Therefore, you shouldn't be looking at GCC options, but at ld options. It seems you want `--print-gc-sections`. However, note that you probably want GCC to put each function in its own section, `-ffunction-sections`. By default GCC will put all functions in the same section, and ld isn't smart enough to eliminate unused functions - it can only eliminate unused sections.

Comment: The `--print-gc-sections` option prints result like this: `Removing unused section  '.text._DriverUnloadHandler' in file '/tmp/ccLoxO8q.ltrans0.ltrans.o'`. So how to find the original C file name?

Comment: And the `-ffunction-sections` doesn't work with assembly code since no compilation is involved. So all functions in assembly code will be in the `.text` section, which renders the `--print-gc-sections` less useful to detect unused functions.

Comment: @smwikipedia: Check `objdump -W /tmp/ccLoxO8q.ltrans0.ltrans.o`

Comment: @smwikipedia: As for assembly, it can be structured in ways which are not expressible as functions. For instance, you cannot call into the middle of a C function; C functions have a single entry point. Assembly is just a sequence of instructiosn, and you can jump to any point in that sequence. In x86, rhere's not even a restriction that you jump to an actual instruction boundary !

Comment: Yes. I agree with you. So these options are kind of useful to C only. But that's good enough for most scenarios. Thanks.

Comment: @smwikipedia: Well, you can of course use `.segment .text.MyAssemblyFoo` to manually create sections in your assembly. That's the double-edged nature of assembly: you can do everything manually, and you must do everythign manually.

Answer (score -1):

[gcov](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov-Intro.html#Gcov-Intro) is what you're looking for.  You have that listed in the question, have you not looked at it?

Comment: Not really, "gcov creates a logfile called sourcefile.gcov which indicates how many times each line of a source file sourcefile.c has executed." This is dynamic analysis not static.