# Does GCC LTO perform cross-file dead code elimination?

Tags: gcc, dead-code, lto

Say I have a function

```
void do_something() {
    //....
    #ifdef FEATURE_X
        feature_x();
    #endif
    //....
}
```

I can compile and run this with no problems; if I want the feature I can pass `-D FEATURE_X` and it works.

However, what if I would like to put `do_something` into another file (And not have to recompile that file as well each time I decide to change the option).  If it was in the same file, I assume that

```
const int FEATURE_X=0;

void do_something() {
    //....
    if(FEATURE_X) {
        feature_x();
    }
    //....
}
```

will use dead code elimination properly, eliminating the call.  If I put this in another file, without LTO,

```
extern const int FEATURE_X;

void do_something() {
    //....
    if(FEATURE_X) {
        feature_x();
    }
    //....
}
```

It will not remove the code (It has no way of knowing).  So, with link time optimization enabled, can the compiler detect the value of `FEATURE_X` at link time, determine if the code is used or not, and remove it if appropriate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC does cross module unreachable function removal, but it will not be able to determine the code is dead in your last testcase, because the constant value of FEATURE_X will be determined too late.

If you will use -D way or put your `const int FEATURE_X=0;` into every module then yes, the code will be eliminated.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  As a note, using backticks instead of regular quotes causes the surrounded text to be "code" typeset (monospace, etc).

Comment: It seems that recent versions of gcc do determine the constant value in time to eliminate dead code now.

Answer (score 0):

**Example showing that LTO leads to dead code elimination**

Test setup:

notmain.c

```
int notmain(int i) {
    return i + 1;
}

int notmain2(int i) {
    return i + 2;
}
```

main.c

```
int notmain(int);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    return notmain(argc);
}
```

**Control experiment without LTO**

Compile and disassemble without LTO:

```
gcc -O3 -c notmain.c
gcc -O3 notmain.o main.c
objdump -d a.out
```

The output contains:

```
0000000000001040 <main>:
    1040:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1044:       e9 f7 00 00 00          jmp    1140 <notmain>
    1049:       0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000001140 <notmain>:
    1140:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1144:       8d 47 01                lea    0x1(%rdi),%eax
    1147:       c3                      ret
    1148:       0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
    114f:       00

0000000000001150 <notmain2>:
    1150:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1154:       8d 47 02                lea    0x2(%rdi),%eax
    1157:       c3                      ret
```

so the useless `notmain2` was not removed.

We can also look at the object size:

```
size a.out
```

which outputs:

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1304     544       8    1856     740 a.out
```

Furthermore, as a bonus, we note that the function call is not inlined:

```
0000000000001040 <main>:
    1040:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1044:       e9 f7 00 00 00          jmp    1140 <notmain>
    1049:       0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

**Observe LTO doing DCE**

```
gcc -c -flto -O3 notmain.c
gcc -flto -O3 notmain.o main.c
objdump -d a.out
```

The output does not contain neither the `notmain` not the `notmain2` symbols. Everything is fully inlined into `main`, which in a single instruction adds 1 to rdi, the first argument, and puts it into the return register eax:

```
0000000000001040 <main>:
    1040:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1044:       8d 47 01                lea    0x1(%rdi),%eax
    1047:       c3                      ret
    1048:       0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

Inlining also mentioned at: [Link-time optimization and inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046547/link-time-optimization-and-inline/61367211#61367211)

Beauty. Checking size:

```
size a.out
```

outputs:

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1217     544       8    1769     6e9 a.out
```

and we see that the text size is smaller as desired due to inline and dead code elimination.

**LTO does DCE even when inlining doesn't happen**

On the above example, it is not clear if function DCE elimination happens only when inlining is involved or not. So let's test it out with:

```
int __attribute__ ((noinline)) notmain(int i) {
    return i + 1;
}
```

Compile and disassemble:

```
gcc -c -flto -O3 notmain.c
gcc -flto -O3 notmain.o main.c
objdump -d a.out
```

The output contains:

```
0000000000001040 <main>:
    1040:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1044:       e9 f7 00 00 00          jmp    1140 <notmain>
    1049:       0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000001140 <notmain>:
    1140:       8d 47 01                lea    0x1(%rdi),%eax
    1143:       c3                      ret
```

and no `notmain2`. Therefore, the useless `notmain2` was removed even though `notmain` wasn't.

**Function removal does not happen when `notmain.c` is compiled with `-O0`**

I don't understand why exactly: [Why GCC does not do function dead code elimination with LTO when compiling the object file with -O0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76702495/why-gcc-does-not-do-function-dead-code-elimination-with-lto-when-compiling-the-o)

Tested on Ubuntu 23.04 amd64, GCC 12.2.0.