# resolve name mangling without c++filt

Tags: c++, linker, name-mangling

I need to remove unused functions from a big C++ project. After reading a while I used this link:  [How can I know which parts in the code are never used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813947/how-can-i-know-which-parts-in-the-code-are-never-used)

I compile on RedHat using makefiles. I added to compiler the flags:
-Wall -Wconversion **-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections**
and to the linker the flags:
**-Wl**,-rpath,**--demangle,--gc-sections,--print-gc-sections**
For some annoying reason I receive the output after mangling even after using **--demangle** option.    For example:

`/usr/bin/ld: Removing unused section '.text._ZN8TRACABLED0Ev' in file 'CMakeFiles/oded.dir/oded.cpp.o'
/usr/bin/ld: Removing unused section '.text._ZN8TRACABLED1Ev' in file 'CMakeFiles/oded.dir/oded.cpp.o'`

So I have 6000 function names I need to unmangle and I cannot use `extern C`.

I can write a script to parse it and use **c++filt**, but Im looking for a solution that will make the linker unmangle the function by itself!

Anyone knows if such a solution exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some annoying reason I receive the output after mangling even after using --demangle option

From `man ld`:

```
--demangle[=style]
--no-demangle

These options control whether to demangle symbol names in
error messages and other output.
```

But these messages:

```
Removing unused section '.text._ZN8TRACABLED0Ev' in file
```

are *not* about symbol names. They are about *section* names, which just happen to *sometimes* include the symbol name. So this is working as documented.

Now, if you really wanted to do something about it, you could develop a linker patch to also demangle section names, and send it to GNU binutils maintainers.

But an easier option might be to simply pipe the messages you want to be demangled through `c++filt`. For example:

```
echo "Removing unused section '.text._ZN8TRACABLED0Ev' in file" |
  sed -e 's/_ZN/ _ZN/' | c++filt
```

produces:

```
Removing unused section '.text.  TRACABLE::~TRACABLE()' in file
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like I will go on a script (: