# Scan for "dead" functions in project / class (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, refactoring

I have a big project with much dead code (big amount of unreferenced functions)

How can I detect functions in a class that are not used?

P.S.: The project uses C++ space, please don't offer ReSharper or .NET addons like this.

Comment: There is a find all references button in visual studio, but it misses a few things sometimes (especially if you have macros or templates). Visual Assist works better, but it's expensive. In any case, if you have virtual functions no-one will be able to tell if they are actually called by just looking at the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I found this documentation for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976.aspx). Maybe the linker can help you with that (***You can use the /VERBOSE option to see the functions that are removed by /OPT:REF and the functions that are folded by /OPT:ICF.***).

> *Controls the optimizations that LINK performs during a build.*
>
> **/OPT:{REF | NOREF}**
>
> **REF | NOREF /OPT:REF** eliminates functions and data that are never
>   referenced; /OPT:NOREF keeps functions and data that are never
>   referenced. When /OFT:REF is enabled, LINK removes unreferenced
>   packaged functions and data. An object contains packaged functions and
>   data (COMDATs) if it was compiled by using the /Gy option. This
>   optimization is known as transitive COMDAT elimination. By default,
>   /OPT:REF is enabled in non-debug builds. To override this default and
>   keep unreferenced COMDATs in the program, specify /OPT:NOREF. You can
>   use the /INCLUDE option to override the removal of a specific symbol.
>   When /OPT:REF is enabled either explicitly or by default, a limited
>   form of /OPT:ICF is enabled that only folds identical functions. If
>   you want /OPT:REF but not /OPT:ICF, you must specify either
>   /OPT:REF,NOICF or /OPT:NOICF. If /DEBUG is specified, the default for
>   /OPT is NOREF, and all functions are preserved in the image. To
>   override this default and optimize a debugging build, specify
>   /OPT:REF. Because /OPT:REF implies /OPT:ICF, we recommend that you
>   also specify /OPT:NOICF to preserve identical functions in debugging
>   builds. This makes it easier to read stack traces and set breakpoints
>   in functions that would otherwise be folded together. The /OPT:REF
>   option disables incremental linking. You have to explicitly mark const
>   data as a COMDAT; use __declspec(selectany). Specifying /OPT:ICF does
>   not enable the /OPT:REF option.

2. [Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4814564/5218277), maybe it will help too. The main recommendation there is to use external tools for static analysis or code coverage.

Answer (score 0):

15 seconds of googling gave me this:

[Link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1324194.aspx?find%20unused%20subroutines%20functions%20in%20visual%20studio)

> In the build menu select run code analysis on your YourProjectName.  In the output window you should see a warning like this for unused sub routines

Comment: That looks like a .Net warning. The native rule set doesn't appear to have this rule.