# Is there a way in qt-creator to check unused/dead code?

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I'm looking for anything, like plugin to qt-creator to highlight unused/dead code in c++. Or maybe there is a standalone gui tool for this. I'm using cmake based project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: clang static analyzer can do dead code detection (although I don't know if it has any integration into Qt Creator.  It is integrated into X-Code if you are able to use that; alternatively you can run it from the command line)

Comment: See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813947/how-can-i-know-which-parts-in-the-code-are-never-used

Answer (score 0):

You can use Coco. It is a tool developed by the Qt group.

Please see:
https://www.qt.io/blog/quality-assurance/find-unused-functions-c-code-coverage

Answer (score 0):

In Qt Creator 12.0.1 try:

Tools / C++ / Find Unused Functions

**Use with caution**.

In my case I had some debug code commented out, but still wanted the possibility of using it, and the debug code called a function that I did not comment out, so it found that, as it should. But I didn't want that deleted just yet.

Also it flagged my "run" function that is a call into another thread, that I think is working correctly, so I don't know if I am doing something wrong or if it shouldn't have flagged it.

But it's nice to find the really dead code and clean it up.