# Clang: Find unused code of dynamic library

Tags: macos, linker, clang++

For simplicity, I have a dynamic library that contains 2 functions:

```
#mylibrary.h
void foo1();
void foo2();
```

Then I have an app that uses only one of this functions:

```
#include "mylibrary.h"
int maint(){
   foo1();
   return 0;
}
```

Is there a way (maybe similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813947/how-can-i-know-which-parts-in-the-code-are-never-used), but for `clang+ld`) to figure out what functions are never called by my app?

Remark: function `foo2()` is used by library itself internally, so `-Wunused` does not help.