# What is the equivalent of Proguard for C/C++ code?

Tags: gcc

This would probably be achieved in the linking stage of the GCC compiler?
But are there any specific references on this stage?

Also, is there a tool that can perform code size reduction by knowing which pieces of code isn't called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compress the final size of your executable using tools like:

- [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) - Ultimate Packet for eXecutables  (Great tool for shrinking any object code file e.g. .exe, .dll, .elf)

Here are a few references regarding stripping code during the gcc/ld compilation or linking phases:

- [How to remove unused C/C++ symbols with GCC and ld?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687630/c-c-gcc-ld-remove-unused-symbols)
- [Dead code detection in legacy C/C++ project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229069/dead-code-detection-in-legacy-c-c-project)

So I imagine this has to be done on a code level and can't be done on compiled code in the way that Java bytecode can be worked with...

Comment: For the obfusication aspect of ProGuard take a look at the answers to this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025494/obfuscating-c-c-code