# What is AST,CFG,CLANG, how can we use it in deadcode removal algorithm?

Tags: c, parsing, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, dead-code

I am about to write a dead-code removal algorithm using C language for an online event with our team.

The requirements are.....

1. To read a C program source file,Which has many forms of dead-codes.
2. And our output should be a file, Which is free from all dead-codes.

While surfing the internet, we came across the SO links...

[How can I know which parts in the code are never used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813947/how-can-i-know-which-parts-in-the-code-are-never-used)

[Dead code detection in legacy C/C++ project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229069/dead-code-detection-in-legacy-c-c-project)

Before seeing these links,we had the basic idea...
   Reading the input C file, line by line using normal file stream and store in an string array.
   Then to analyze those strings and determine the very basic dead codes like if(0) and if(1) etc..
   And making a stack, for maintaining the parenthesis. And so more...

But this has a great problem, that this idea will lead us to do more with string operations rather than removing dead-codes.

But After seeing these link...
We came to know about 
Clang library,Abstract Syntax Tree,Control-Flow-Graph etc...

But we are very newbie to those libraries and those concepts. 
We came to know that they are used to parse the C code.

Hence we need some basic ideas about these AST,CFG and some basic guidance, explaining how can we use 
that in our code...

Can we include that clang library as a normal library like math.h?

Where can we download that library?

Does we can use those Clang libraries in windows?

Comment: Just to get the idea: try using the following chain (assuming you've got llvm and clang binaries installed) - `clang -cc1 yourfile.c; opt -O3 -globaldce -dce yourfile.bc -o optfile.bc; llc -march=c optfile.bc`.

Comment: What kind of "online event" proposes this as a task for folks with no experience doing it?

Comment: ... and the problem of doing this for C is one hard task, and doing it for C++ is a much harder task because C++ is much more complex (including the C problem in effect as just a part).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can explain to you the concept of control flow graphs, but I am not familiar with the library itself.

The concept is simple. Imagine any sequential lines of code (that is without `if`, `goto` or function call or labels) as one node of a graph. Every `goto` or function call creates a directional link from the current node to the node where the `goto` label is or the function it is calling. Remember that a function itself could be a graph and not a simple node, because it may have `if`s or other function calls inside. Each function call also creates a directional link from leaf nodes of the function (where the function `return`s) to the node containing the codes right after the function call. (That can create a lot of links outgoing from the function graph because the function can be called in many parts of the code)

Likewise, if you have an `if`, you have two direction links from the current node to both the `if` part and the `else` part of the `if` statement (unless you detect `if(0)` or `if(1)` like you said in which case there is only one link to the proper location)

The root of your graph is the entry point of `main`. Now what you must do to find dead code is to simply traverse the graph from the root position (using DFS or BFS for example) and in the end see which nodes were NOT visited. This shows you the dead codes, that is places in the code that no matter what direction your program takes, it won't reach those locations.

If you want to implement this yourself, you can take a recursive approach (similar to parsing the code but simpler). For example if you see an `if` you say:

```
typedef char *line;
FlowGraph *get_flow_graph(line *code)
{
    FlowGraph *current_node = malloc(sizeof *current_node);
    current_node->flow_to = malloc(some_maximum * sizeof *current_node->flow_to);
    current_node->flow_to_count = 0;
    ...
    if (is_if_statement(code[0]))
    {
        FlowGraph *if_part = get_flow_graph(code + 1);
        FlowGraph *else_part = get_flow_graph(code + find_matching_else(code));
        current_node->flow_to[current_node->flow_to_count++] = if_part;
        current_node->flow_to[current_node->flow_to_count++] = else_part;
    }
    else
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does the flow graph include the results of indirect function calls? If not, this will decide that indirectly-called functions are dead. Oops.

Comment: Indirect function calls? You mean function call within function call? Or using function pointers? In the first case (function call in function call), this works because it recursively creates the graph for the called functions too. If you mean the second, you are right. That DOES create some complication. However, that is very difficult to determine at compile time because pointers can change. So one can go with assuming every function could be called once and find the dead code in each function separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can see examples of [control and data flow](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/FlowAnalysis.html) graphs extracted by the [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html).

We have done this on very large applications (26 million lines of C) using DMS's data flow analysis machinery and its [C Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html), including a points-to analysis, which is a practical necessity if you really want to find dead functions in a large C system.